# Using HttpClient with different WebProxy per request in .NET 6

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

In .NET 4.7.2, the official recommendation is to use HttpClient in a singleton pattern as much as possible. However, in my project I need to set a different WebProxy for each request, and there are multiple threads accessing it concurrently. This requirement clearly cannot be met using a singleton pattern.

Currently I am still using a combination of HttpWebRequest and HttpResponse from the RestSharp v106 library to accomplish this. Now I want to migrate my project to .NET 6 for development, and I have some questions:

1. Given my requirements, should I use HttpClient in .NET 6 instead?
2. If I do use HttpClient, since I need a different WebProxy per request, is creating a new HttpClient instance for each request the right approach? I've tried modifying the Proxy property but that doesn't work - I have to create a new HttpClient and set the Proxy to get it to work.
3. If not using HttpClient, what alternative should I use? I noticed RestSharp versions above v106 are all based on HttpClient, which is why I've stuck with v106 so far.

I would appreciate any suggestions on the best approach to take for making HTTP requests with varying WebProxy settings in a multithreaded .NET 6 application. Please let me know if I should provide any other clarifying details!

Comment: Look up the HttpClientFactory, in particular, using it with _Named_ HttpClients (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#named-clients)

Comment: How many proxies do you have? are you creating proxies based on request or you have a set of proxies that will select randomly?

Comment: You won't be able to directly change the proxy of an HttpClient. You will need to create a new instance for each proxy. If you have few proxy, maybe you can add your HttpClients in a dictionary. If not, you're not going to escape having to create an instance per request. Don't forget the using statement to dispose them. Keep an eye on the memory leaks, but the GC should handle this correctly

Comment: You are using either HTTP 1.0 or 1.1 which requires a new connection for each request/response.  HTTPClient and HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse all use the same connection method.  The only different is the default https headers and HttpClient may be a little easier to use.  With HTTPClient the library does some of the work where with HTTPWeb you have to write some of the code yourself that the library does not do.